# MySQL INSERT query syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to make a mysql insert like this one here

```
<http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp >  
     INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

I am trying to insert the values below into the table userbase.

```
54007033331, Codi Y, Male, pub, http://google.com/ggg.jpg


INSERT INTO userbase (id,name,gender,publicity,pic) VALUES (54007033331, Codi Y, Male, pub, http://google.com/ggg.jpg)

MySQL query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Y, Male, pub, http://google.com/ggg.jpg)' at line 1
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction of how to fix this syntax error?

Comment: Dude, strings needs to be quoted in mysql (and most other languages).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should quote properly string and char values in query.

```
 INSERT INTO userbase (id,display,gender,publicity,pic) 
 VALUES (54007033331, 'Codi Y', 'Male', 'pub', 'http://google.com/ggg.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, put quotes around String values.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your column types I can't be sure, but I would hazard a guess that the values for all bar the first column are strings and the values need to be quoted with single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO userbase (id,display,gender,publicity,pic)
    VALUES (54007033331, 'Codi Y', 'Male', 'pub', 'http://google.com/ggg.jpg')
```

Though if you're doing this programmatically, you should be using placeholders:

```
INSERT INTO userbase (id,display,gender,publicity,pic)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and value binding.